# Accessing Android getString() by sending in variable

Tags: android

I have a very large xml file that I need to pull strings from based on what was selected from a spinner. The "Week 1 Early..." in the following code is what was selected on the spinner.

```
switch (selectedItem) {
        case "Week 1 Early - 9/7/2014":
            r2c1a = getString(R.string.w1er2c1away);
            r2c1aID = getResources().getIdentifier("com.myApp:drawable/" + r2c1a, null, null);              
            loadBitmap(r2c1aID, imgViewr2c1a);
```

So if "Week 1 Early..." was selected from the spinner it would retrieve the string value from the xml file where the string name was w1er2c1away.  This returns a team name, "Bears" for instance.  The following line gets the resource ID for Bears and then loadBitmap loads the Bears image into the imgViewr2c1a Image View.  I need to know how I can replace "w1er2c1away" with a string variable name.  I've tried changing the code to

```
            case "Week 1 Early - 9/7/2014":
            //R2C1
            String tempText = "w1er2c1away";
            r2c1a = getString(R.string.tempText);
```

but I get an error under the second "tempText" that says "tempText cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to change `"com.myApp:string/"`, but I think you need to use:

```
r2c1a = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("com.myApp:string/" + tempText, null, null));
```